# How can I get the name of the nav-tab that is parent to current element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do know how to get the name of nav-tab when it is shown, but I am trying to get the name of the tab of a child element when the child element is changed.  Just getting the name of the last tab clicked/shown won't help. I am using asp.net MVC Razor and need to find out what changed on the page and on what tabs.  The user technically could click tabs without changing anything.  I tried doing something like this:

```
    $('body').on('change', '.form-control', function () {
        var tab = this.closest('nav-tab');
    })
```

I have also tried:

```
    $('body').on('change', '.form-control', function () {
        var tab = this.closest('.nav-tab');
    })
```

but that did not work.  There may be a better way to accomplish what I need.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `'nav-tab'` as a CSS selector won't give you anything, as `nav-tab` is not a valid HTML tab name. Was this meant to be a CSS class? If so you forgot the `.` at the start of the selector.

Comment: I tried that as well, I guess I should have added that to my list of things that I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked through the DOM to see where its nested? I've had luck in tables just going up to the TR then doing a find with the class. Maybe this sample will help?

```
$(".ctxMenu li").click(function () {
    var thisLink = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[id$='" + $(this).attr("data-action") + "']").attr("id");
    if (thisLink != "undefined") {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("input[id$='" + $(this).attr("data-action") + "']").click();
    }
    $(".ctxMenu").hide(100);
});
```

```
$(".jqSaveChangeDiv").change(function (e) {
    $(this).closest("div").find(".jqQuickUpdate2").trigger("click");
    console.log("Updated " + $(this).closest("div").find(".jqQuickUpdate2").attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: It is not in a table, it is in a tab-pane, but there are several divs between the element and the tab-pane like 5 or 6.

Comment: I added a div example above...  the closest("div") should get the first parent div of the tab-pane, then the .find(".nav-tab") should get it.  Do a console log to check